# Laravel amazon ses gives Swift_TransportException

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, email

So i have followed the guide on how to set up a mail with `laravel` and `amazon simple mail service`

in my `mail.php`

```
    'driver' => env('ses', 'smtp'),
```

and this is my mail class:

```
namespace App\Mail;

use App\rental_request;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class AccountDetails extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mail.accountdetails')
            ->with([
                'password' => $this->user->password,
                'name' => $this->user->username,
            ]);
    }
}
```

When I attempt to send a mail I get the following:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

**My mail.php**:

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('ses', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

**My .Env file**:

```
    APP_NAME=*****
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:S3RvGYDc4ApvYauVV8Q6haaX2cFC0wWneGFSoP1z2BQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=****
DB_USERNAME=****
DB_PASSWORD=****

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379php

MAIL_DRIVER=ses
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=info
MAIL_PASSWORD=***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

SES_KEY=****
SES_SECRET=****
```

Comment: Did you also include the `secret` and `region` for the driver in `mail.php`?  Also in your `.env` file, you have a variable named `ses` and it's value is `ses`?

Comment: i set the key and values in the .env:

SES_KEY=****
SES_SECRET=*****

Comment: you can only send emails to a SES verified email address in development mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you need to set your `MAIL_DRIVER` variable in your .env file to `ses`, then change your mail.php to match...

Replace

```
'driver' => env('ses', 'smtp'),
```

With

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
```

The problem I suspect is `env('ses', 'smtp')` will not return `ses`, it will look in your .env file for a variable named `ses` and return its value.

Comment: The thing you say should be in my mail.php isnt that suppose to go into my services.php?

Comment: ive attempted to do that with your driver however without any luck

Comment: ive added my env file to the question